# Do you say "this" on protected members?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, inheritance

**Background**

I have never had a formal class in OOP/OOD although I understand how the protected members work. Being accessible by any instance/derived class, they are thereby less private (more accessible) than *private*.

Now, what I am confused on... is how to access the protected members *within* the class for C#. I have seen examples of developers doing it in two different ways. The first way I have seen people doing it, is by calling on the keyword `this` in front of the member variable such as in [this example here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/protected). The second way that I have seen people using protected member is by *not* calling on `this` and just calling the member itself. [This tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance.htm) over at tutorials point, does not use the `this` keyword.

Now, there's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword) on StackOverflow. One of the answers states that "to qualify members hidden by similar name" does this include `protected` members?

**Question**

Are you supposed to use the `this` keyword on a protected member? I have seen it with/without.

Comment: Yes, the question and two topmost answers of your last link include `protected` members, they say all there is to say about this (pun intendend),

Comment: This is purely opinion. For example Killian Foth's answer says you shouldn't. However, I *always* use this to access member variables as I think it's cleaner.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Good to know, why do you think it's cleaner? I guess in one way, it is an extra keyword... wouldn't that make it less clean? Or you mean maybe by adding the keyword, that if a parameter happens to have the same name in the future, you will have already used `this`.

Comment: I'm not going to get into my personal thoughts here. The point is, different people are going to have different opinions. Such questions aren't a good fit for a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: There two things in this. Which is best to use `this` or not use `this`. That is a very opinionated discussion. The other part is if `this` is required for protected/private/public. Though this is a rather fundamental question on syntax and perhaps better suited for SO and there are probably duplicates there. It would be better close this as a duplicate of those and not as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the coding guidelines where you work or on the projects you work on.

You will find that there are a lot of people who are totally for or totally against the use of `this` unless it is needed as in the example given in @KilianFoths answer.

It does not have anything to do with public, protected or private.

Comment: I guess I've always had variables of different names than the ones passed in anyways, so I'd have never needed this... and have used it for every single thing I've ever done. Good to know that I can change that from now on.

Answer (score 4):

No, you shouldn't use `this` redundantly. It adds unnecessary clutter and makes you look as if you're not sure what fields your class has.

The only reason that many people do this is that they often see this introductory example:

```
public Foo(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

and wrongly assume that you *always* have to use `this`, when in fact you only need it to disambiguate it against a local variable with the same name.

Comment: Oh okay, so it has nothing to do with public/private at all really?

Comment: @StevieV: No, it has not. What makes you think it has?

Comment: "It adds unnecessary clutter and makes you look as if you're not sure what fields your class has." - and the can of worms has been opened ;-)

Comment: It has a *slight* connection. Private/protected member fields are the ones that absolutely *require* constructor/accessor injection, which leads to the pattern above, which encourages excessive use of `this`.